# How to change the destination output when a VBA code reaches line 1,048,576

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a code that shows all the possible combinations when 8 dice are rolled. The problem is: there's almost 1.7million combinations and excel only has 1,048,576 lines, so VBA keeps giving me an error (Run-time error '1004': Method 'Offset' of object 'Range' failed). How can I fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
Sub combinations()

Dim c1() As Variant
Dim c2() As Variant
Dim c3() As Variant
Dim c4() As Variant
Dim c5() As Variant
Dim c6() As Variant
Dim c7() As Variant
Dim c8() As Variant
Dim out() As Variant
Dim j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r As Long


Dim col1 As Range
Dim col2 As Range
Dim col3 As Range
Dim col4 As Range
Dim col5 As Range
Dim col6 As Range
Dim col7 As Range
Dim col8 As Range
Dim out1 As Range


Set col1 = Range("A1:A6")
Set col2 = Range("B1:B6")
Set col3 = Range("C1:C6")
Set col4 = Range("D1:D6")
Set col5 = Range("E1:E6")
Set col6 = Range("F1:F6")
Set col7 = Range("G1:G6")
Set col8 = Range("H1:H6")

c1 = col1
c2 = col2
c3 = col3
c4 = col4
c5 = col5
c6 = col6
c7 = col7
c8 = col8

Set out1 = Range("J2", Range("Q2").Offset(UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4) * UBound(c5) * UBound(c6) * UBound(c7) * UBound(c8)))
out = out1

j = 1
k = 1
l = 1
m = 1
n = 1
o = 1
p = 1
q = 1
r = 1


Do While j <= UBound(c1)
    Do While k <= UBound(c2)
        Do While l <= UBound(c3)
            Do While m <= UBound(c4)
                Do While n <= UBound(c5)
                    Do While o <= UBound(c6)
                        Do While p <= UBound(c7)
                            Do While q <= UBound(c8)
                            out(r, 1) = c1(j, 1)
                            out(r, 2) = c2(k, 1)
                            out(r, 3) = c3(l, 1)
                            out(r, 4) = c4(m, 1)
                            out(r, 5) = c5(n, 1)
                            out(r, 6) = c6(o, 1)
                            out(r, 7) = c7(p, 1)
                            out(r, 8) = c8(q, 1)
                            r = r + 1
                            q = q + 1
                        Loop
                        q = 1
                        p = p + 1
                    Loop
                    p = 1
                    o = o + 1
                Loop
                o = 1
                n = n + 1
            Loop
            n = 1
            m = m + 1
        Loop
        m = 1
        l = l + 1
    Loop
    l = 1
    k = k + 1
Loop
k = 1
j = j + 1
out = out1
Loop

out1.Value = out
End Sub
```

How do I add in the Loop that when it reaches line 1,048,576, it should start running the combinations in a different set of columns? Ideally, I would like it to start running the code in columns T2 - AA2 once J2 - Q2 have been filled.

Comment: `out(r, 1).Offset(0, z) = c1(j, 1)` etc. Start with z=0 and when r gets to 1 million, reset r to 1 and increment z by 10

Comment: Write it to a text file first. It will be faster else your excel will become slow. Once the text file is written then load the file in memory and then write to excel file in chunks.

Comment: How do I write the code so that r resets to 1 when it gets to 1 million? Sorry, I'm new to VBA so this might be a dumb question.

Comment: `If r>1000000 Then: r=1:z=10:End If`

Comment: Do you actually have to show these values? you could just have them in memory and use it for whatever your down stream task is?

Comment: @Zac I do need to know the values because I plan on creating a frequency chart.

Comment: @TimWilliams my code now reads: 

    out(r, 1).Offset(0, Z) = c1(j, 1)
    out(r, 2).Offset(0, Z) = c2(k, 1)
    ....
    out(r, 8).Offset(0, Z) = c8(q, 1)
    r = r + 1
    If r > 1000000 Then
    r = 1: Z = 10
    End If
    q = q + 1

Sorry I can't figure out how to make this a code block on this website...

Comment: You can edit your question and add your code there.

Comment: Is database not an option? You could enter the data directly into a database and run your chart from values in the database

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you trying the next approach. Anyhow, it will take long time for big data range...

It proposes using of a second array, to be loaded if the total combinations number will exceed the maximum allowed. It could use the same array, dropping the data at the maximum limit and being `Redim` for the new dimensions, but I was afraid that the meaning of the idea may be missed...

```
Sub testCombinations_()
 '.......
 Dim out2 As Range, outBis As Variant, acceptR As Double
 Const maxR As Long = 1048574
 acceptR = UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4) * UBound(c5) * UBound(c6) * UBound(c7) * UBound(c8)
 If acceptR > maxR Then
    Set out1 = Range("J2", Range("Q2").Offset(maxR))
    Set out2 = Range("T2", Range("AA2").Offset(acceptR - maxR))
    out = out1.value
    outBis = out2.value ' only for easy array dimensioning
 Else
    Set out1 = Range("J2", Range("Q2").Offset(acceptR))
    out = out1.value
 End If
 'follow your code...
 '..........
            Do While q <= UBound(c8)
                If r <= maxR Then
                    out(r, 1) = c1(j, 1)
                    out(r, 2) = c2(k, 1)
                    out(r, 3) = c3(L, 1)
                    out(r, 4) = c4(m, 1)
                    out(r, 5) = c5(n, 1)
                    out(r, 6) = c6(o, 1)
                    out(r, 7) = c7(p, 1)
                    out(r, 8) = c8(q, 1)
                    r = r + 1
                    q = q + 1
                    If r = maxR Then r = 1
                 Else
                    outBis(r, 1) = c1(j, 1)
                    outBis(r, 2) = c2(k, 1)
                    outBis(r, 3) = c3(L, 1)
                    outBis(r, 4) = c4(m, 1)
                    outBis(r, 5) = c5(n, 1)
                    outBis(r, 6) = c6(o, 1)
                    outBis(r, 7) = c7(p, 1)
                    outBis(r, 8) = c8(q, 1)
                    r = r + 1
                    q = q + 1
                 End If
            Loop
    '.........
    out1.value = out
    If UBound(outBis) > 1 Then out2.value = outBis
End Sub
```

Like a general observation: `Dim j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r As Long` will Dim all enumeration `As Variant` and only the last one `As Long`. And it is difficult to follow such a long vertical code... I would use: `j = 1: k = 1: l = 1:...` and so on for all vertical "arrangement". The vertical way is nice and make the code clearer only for a small number of variables. It is not a must, of course...

The code is, of course, not tested and it may need to be improved or corrected...

Answer (score 0):

Tested:

```
Sub combinations()

    Const max_rows As Long = 1000000

    Dim c(1 To 8) As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim i As Long, totRows As Long, out()
    Dim x1 As Long, x2 As Long, x3 As Long, x4 As Long
    Dim x5 As Long, x6 As Long, x7 As Long, x8 As Long
    Dim rngOut As Range

    totRows = 1
    For i = 1 To 8
        c(i) = Range("A1:A6").Offset(0, i - 1).Value
        totRows = totRows * UBound(c(i), 1)
    Next i

    Debug.Print totRows

    ReDim out(1 To max_rows, 1 To 8)
    Set rngOut = Range("A8")
    r = 1
    For x1 = 1 To UBound(c(1), 1)
    For x2 = 1 To UBound(c(2), 1)
    For x3 = 1 To UBound(c(3), 1)
    For x4 = 1 To UBound(c(4), 1)
    For x5 = 1 To UBound(c(5), 1)
    For x6 = 1 To UBound(c(6), 1)
    For x7 = 1 To UBound(c(7), 1)
    For x8 = 1 To UBound(c(8), 1)
        out(r, 1) = c(1)(x1, 1)
        out(r, 2) = c(2)(x2, 1)
        out(r, 3) = c(3)(x3, 1)
        out(r, 4) = c(4)(x4, 1)
        out(r, 5) = c(5)(x5, 1)
        out(r, 6) = c(6)(x6, 1)
        out(r, 7) = c(7)(x7, 1)
        out(r, 8) = c(8)(x8, 1)
        If r = max_rows Then
            'hit row limit: output and move over
            rngOut.Resize(max_rows, 8).Value = out
            Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(0, 10)
            ReDim out(1 To max_rows, 1 To 8)
            r = 0
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Next x8
    Next x7
    Next x6
    Next x5
    Next x4
    Next x3
    Next x2
    Next x1

    rngOut.Resize(max_rows, 8).Value = out

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim. I already got my code to work so I didn't get a chance to test this one. Thanks though!